# getting empty fields when extracting data from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have this code :

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

and the  CSV file containes data in Arabic language, when I open the page in the browser I get empty values for the second field in all lines but in the CSV file it contains data. so when there is arabic data I get it empty in the page when display it **- NOT All arabic data, most of them -**

When I put a file that doesn't contain arabic data, every thing is ok.

What is the problem?

EDIT :

lines from CSV file :

[image]

I added them as photo because when copy / past will not put data in the right order

and I get in the output this photo :

[image]

Comment: can you provide a couple of input lines for us to test with.

Comment: If you look at the CSV file directly in the browser, does the arabic display?

Comment: @tandu: yes, I can see them when I set the page code to windows-1256

Comment: From the function reference on fgetscv: Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Possibly changing your locale settings could work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is due to a different language/character set being used to create the CSV, and read it into PHP.

If the character sets are not the same, PHP tries to make a conversion. In this case, it looks like the conversion is failing such that the data appears to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried with data of different languages, but when I read that csv file using php code, the data was converted into **????????**. Tried a lot with different languages data in csv file but found no successful results. So I came to one conclusion that if we want to deal with spreadsheet file that involve multiple languages other that English **[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)** would be the best option. It is a wonderful library. It would certainly help you out.